# Text file parsing C++ | seperated by whitespace .

Tags: c++, parsing, text

I have a text file like this

```
Path 
827 196
847 195
868 194
889 193
909 191
929 191
951 189
971 186
991 185
1012 185
Path
918 221
927 241
931 261
931 281
930 301
931 321
927 341
923 361
921 382
```

I am reading every line in a text file using getline function , i want to parse the 2 numbers in a single line into two different integer variables .The code i have so far is .

```
int main()
{

  vector<string> text_file;

  int no_of_paths=0;

  ifstream ifs( "ges_t.txt" );
  string temp;

  while( getline( ifs, temp ) )
  {
          if (temp2.compare("path") != 0)
          {
//Strip temp string and separate the values into integers here.
          }

  }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int a, b;
stringstream ss(temp);
ss >> a >> b;
```

Comment: how come you can separate string from stringstream and save them as integer , without the call of atoi() function ?.

Comment: `atoi` is the C way of doing things. Using IOstreams and the [extraction operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) is the C++ way of doing things.

Comment: @rajat: Voting-up is the Stack Overflow way of saying OK cool thanks! :)

Comment: i was going to do that ,after i finish understanding everything .

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream ifs("ges_t.txt");

for (std::string line; std::getline(ifs, line); )
{
    if (line == "Path") { continue; }

    std::istringstream iss(line);
    int a, b;

    if (!(iss >> a >> b) || iss.get() != EOF) { /* error! die? */ }

    std::cout << "You said, " << a << ", " << b << ".\n";
}
```

Comment: This gives an error : variable ‘std::istringstream iss’ has initializer but incomplete type

Comment: @rajat: did you include the header?

Comment: Note that despite the error checking, this will still accept lines like `123 456 abc`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The OP didn't request a format validation of his input, did he? (If you want, you can append an `iss.getc() && !iss` of course.)

Comment: @KerrekSB The OP didn't have to.  _Any_ time you read from an external source, you verify that the format is correct.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Hm, fair enough. Amended.

Answer (score 1):

Given a string with two integers:

```
std::istringstream src( temp );
src >> int1 >> int2 >> std::ws;
if ( ! src || src.get() != EOF ) {
    //  Format error...
}
```

Note that you might want to trim whitespace before comparing for
`"path"` as well.  (Trailing whitespace can be particularly pernicious,
since it can't be seen in a normal editor.)